# Using Rails for heavy imgae manipualtion / large file conversion (and concurrent users)

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

How well does rails handle concurrent request when the controller is executing computation intensive tasks such as .wav to .mp3 conversion or image conversion tasks (or uploading of large files)? It is my understanding that frameworks such as .net handle this more efficiently, or?

Comment: That's what background processing is for... regardless of what web framework you use.  Web servers are for serving requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conversions should be done in background jobs. Me and Github use [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) for that. The upload and other heavy I/O stuff is handled by NodeJS. You can enqueue a Resque Job via NodeJS.

So our setup looks like:

```
Client -[upload]-> NodeJS -[stores upload temporarily and enqueues Job]-> Resque (processing) -> Storage
```

it's completely non-blocking and the benefit of Resque is that you can access your whole Rails environment like Models, Helpers etc.

The actual conversion is done by native programs like ffmpeg etc. which we spawn in the resque job.